# Template Literal Function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that turns an array into modal window links as a template literal.

1. The code that creates the links works fine outside of the function
2. But once it gets rendered in the function it no longer works. I can't find any errors, but it does NOT work.
3. However, if I copy the HTML that the function renders and save that as actual HTML, that works fine on its own.
4. A good chunk of the JavaScript portion of the code is posted below. A full version is on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/vYrLMyR?editors=1111).
5. There are two sections in the example on Codepen:
6. The first section has the code as it's rendered by the function.
7. The second section is copied from the Elements tab in Developer Tools and saved as actual HTML.

   ```
   "use strict";

   const modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");
   const modalWin = document.querySelector(".modal-window");
   const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close-modal");
   const modal_iframe = document.getElementById("modal_iframe");

   modalBtns.forEach((item) => {
     item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
       let modal = e.currentTarget;
       if (modal.dataset.target) {
         let modalID = modal.dataset.target;
         document.getElementById(modalID).style.display = "block";
       }

       if (modal.dataset.iframe) {
         modal_iframe.src = modal.dataset.iframe;
         document
           .querySelector(".button-footer")
           .addEventListener("click", function () {
             window.open(modal.dataset.iframe, "_blank");
           });
       }

       if (modal.dataset.header) {
         document.querySelector(
           ".modal-header"
         ).innerHTML = `<h1>${modal.dataset.header}</h1>`;
       }

       if (modal.dataset.dimensions) {
         document
           .querySelector(".modal-window")
           .setAttribute("style", modal.dataset.dimensions);
       }

       function loadIframe() {
         let frame = document.getElementById("modal_window");
         frame.style.height =
           frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
       }
       if (document.querySelector("#modal_window")) {
         setTimeout(function () {
               loadIframe;
             }, 2000);
           }

   if (modal.dataset.reload && modal.dataset.reload === "1") {
     document
       .querySelector(".close-modal")
       .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
         console.log("parent.location.reload() pending...");
         parent.location.reload();
       });
   }
   /*======= All EventListeners Below Close Modal ================*/
   closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
     document.querySelector(".modal-background").style.display = "none";
   });
   window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
     if (e.currentTarget === document.querySelector(".modal-background")) {
       document.querySelector(".modal-background").style.display = "none";
     }
   });
   document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
     if (e.key === "Escape") {
       document.querySelector(".modal-background").style.display = "none";
     }
   });
     });
   });

   const main = document.querySelector("main");

   const modal_links = [
     {
       link: "https://notation.netcentrx.net/staff/",
       header: "Musical Staff",
       thb: "notation",
       w_h: "min-width:60vw;max-width:600px;height:650px",
       reload: 0
     },
     {
       link: "https://wsl.netcentrx.net/",
       header: "WSL Commands",
       thb: "wsl",
       w_h: "min-width:60vw;max-width:600px;height:650px",
       reload: 0
     }
   ];

   let modalLink = "";
   function createModalLinks(
     link,
     modalID,
     header,
     img,
     w_h = "width:90vw;height:600px",
     reload = "0"
   ) {
         modalLink = `
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modal-button" onclick="console.log('onclick handler:${link}');" data-header="${header}" data-target="${modalID}" data-iframe="${link}" data-dimensions="${w_h};margin-top:20px" data-reload="${reload}">
       <img src="https://resume.netcentrx.net/examples/${img}.jpg" title="${img}"    width="50">
     </a>
   `;
     return modalLink;
       }
       let theLinks = "";
       modal_links.forEach((item) => {
         theLinks += createModalLinks(
           item.link,
           "modal_window",
           item.header,
           item.thb,
           item.w_h,
           item.reload
         );
       });
       main.innerHTML = theLinks;
   ```

My apologies in advance for it not being stripped down to just the bare minimum. But in order to replicate the problem, it required more code than it probably should have had. I've been reworking this for the better part of a day without any insight as to what the real problem is. I've been creating functions using template literals just like this for years now, usually with a high success rate. Whatever the problem is, I need to know so I can get past it. The only anomaly that I spotted is that–in the version on Codepen–the only thing that doesn't work in that version is once the modal is displayed clicking on the background does not dismiss the modal like it does elsewhere. If that's significant as to what the problem may be, I'm not sure what the connection is.

Usually when I take the time to painstakingly write everything out like this I typically either spot the problem or figure out an alternative solution so there's no need to actually post a question, but this does not appear to be one of those times. As always, your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to just be timing. Your code is executed in order, and the first part gets all of the modal buttons on the page and sets the appropriate event listeners. Then the second part of your code adds 2 modal buttons, which were not present earlier.

By simply wrapping the first part of your code in a function and calling it later (or swapping the order of those two parts of code), everything works as expected.

```js
"use strict";

const _InitModal = () => {
  const modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");
  const modalWin = document.querySelector(".modal-window");
  const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close-modal");
  const modal_iframe = document.getElementById("modal_iframe");

  modalBtns.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      console.log("e.currentTarget = " + e.currentTarget);
      let modal = e.currentTarget;
      console.log("modal = " + modal);
      if (modal.dataset.target) {
        let modalID = modal.dataset.target;
        console.log("modal.dataset.target = " + modal.dataset.target);
        document.getElementById(modalID).style.display = "block";
      }

      if (modal.dataset.iframe) {
        modal_iframe.src = modal.dataset.iframe;
        document
          .querySelector(".button-footer")
          .addEventListener("click", function () {
            window.open(modal.dataset.iframe, "_blank");
          });
      }

      if (modal.dataset.header) {
        document.querySelector(
          ".modal-header"
        ).innerHTML = `<h1>${modal.dataset.header}</h1>`;
        console.log(`modal.dataset.header = ${modal.dataset.header}`);
      }

      if (modal.dataset.dimensions) {
        document
          .querySelector(".modal-window")
          .setAttribute("style", modal.dataset.dimensions);
      }

      function loadIframe() {
        let frame = document.getElementById("modal_window");
        frame.style.height =
          frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
      if (document.querySelector("#modal_window")) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          loadIframe;
        }, 2000);
      }
      // e.preventDefault();

      if (modal.dataset.reload && modal.dataset.reload === "1") {
        document
          .querySelector(".close-modal")
          .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            console.log("parent.location.reload() pending...");
            parent.location.reload();
          });
      }
      /*======= All EventListeners Below Close Modal ================*/
      closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        document.querySelector(".modal-background").style.display = "none";
      });
      window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        console.log("e.currentTarget = " + e.currentTarget);
        if (e.currentTarget === document.querySelector(".modal-background")) {
          document.querySelector(".modal-background").style.display = "none";
        }
      });
      document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
          console.log("e=" + e);
          document.querySelector(".modal-background").style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    });
  });
}








const main = document.querySelector("main");

const modal_links = [
  {
    link: "https://notation.netcentrx.net/staff/",
    header: "Musical Staff",
    thb: "notation",
    w_h: "min-width:60vw;max-width:600px;height:650px",
    reload: 0
  },
  {
    link: "https://wsl.netcentrx.net/",
    header: "WSL Commands",
    thb: "wsl",
    w_h: "min-width:60vw;max-width:600px;height:650px",
    reload: 0
  }
];

function createModalLinks(
  link,
  modalID,
  header,
  img,
  w_h = "width:90vw;height:600px",
  reload = "0"
) {
  let modalLink = "";
  modalLink = `
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modal-button" onclick="console.log('onclick handler:${link}');" data-header="${header}" data-target="${modalID}" data-iframe="${link}" data-dimensions="${w_h};margin-top:20px" data-reload="${reload}">
    <img src="https://resume.netcentrx.net/examples/${img}.jpg" title="${img}" width="50">
  </a>`;
  return modalLink;
}
let theLinks = "";
modal_links.forEach((item) => {
  theLinks += createModalLinks(
    item.link,
    "modal_window",
    item.header,
    item.thb,
    item.w_h,
    item.reload
  );
});
main.innerHTML = theLinks;

_InitModal();
```

```css
.modal-background {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  z-index: 9999;
  background: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.6);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.modal-window {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border: 1px groove #ccc;
  /* box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999, 2px 2px 2px #000; */
}

.close-modal:hover,
.close-modal:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  transition: 1s;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999, 2px 2px 2px #000;
}

button.close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.75rem;
  right: -0.75rem;
  padding: 0.05rem 0.75rem;
  background: #999;
  color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

button.close-modal::before {
  content: "\D7";
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.modal-window {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
.modal-header {
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
.modal-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.modal-footer {
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 0.1rem groove #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-footer {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px outset #aaa;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  color: #999;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-footer:hover {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  color: #555;
  border: 1px inset #ddd;
  text-shadow: 0.05rem 0.05rem 0.05rem #ccc, 0.055rem 0.055rem 0.055rem #999,
    0.06rem 0.06rem 0.06rem #333;
  transition: 1s;
}

.close-btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #f00;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#modal_iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button.modal-button {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 0px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-button-img {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 0.1rem groove #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sepia:hover {
  filter: sepia(150%);
}
/* 
.none {
  display: none;  
}
 */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    bottom: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    bottom: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.container {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

main,
aside {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
span {
  font-size: 75%;
  background: #ffff0055;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal_window" class="modal-background">
  <div class="modal-window">
    <button class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
    <div class="modal-header"></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <iframe src="#" id="modal_iframe" frameborder="0">If you'd have had a real browser, I wouldn't be boring you with this now...</iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><button class="button-footer">Open In New Tab</button></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2><code>main</code> Content Rendered By JavaScript</h2>
  <main>
    Main
  </main>
  <span>working now</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works a treat... That never even occurred to me (obviously). How did you deduce that as being the issue? (Here's the updated version of it: https://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/KKezygo?editors=1111)